# Is the GeForce 940MX good enough for graphic design?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

I want to build this laptop for graphic design purposes (Photoshop, illustrator, indesign, ect). No 3D for the moment.

The laptop specifications are:

- Dell Vostro 5568
- Intel Core i7 7500U 2700 Mhz
- 8GB DDR4
- 256GB SSD
- GeForce 940MX

I am most fearful of the graphics card, as it is not listed in the [Illustrator requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/il_he/illustrator/system-requirements.html).

Is it good enough?

I am really trying to keep the price and weight down, and upping the graphics card won't allow that.

Comment: Giving us your workload, budget and weight requirements would be prefered, as it would allow us to answer your question in-depth. For your current dillema, note that several Intel intergrated graphics chipsets are listed. Thus, it is likely that it would work (both the intergrated and dedicated graphics outperform, e.g. the 4600 handily), though whether it will perform well is questionable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is more than enough. 
You should notice that this card is listed in the website as:

> NVIDIA GeForce GTX Series (4xx, 5xx, 6xx, 7xx, 9xx, Titan)

It is also far more powerful than any of the Intel iGPUs listed.

Keep in mind that 2D-focused work stresses out the CPU more than the GPU, and that i7-7500u might slow you down a bit since it's a dual-core CPU. I'd recommend you a laptop with a better CPU and cheaper GPU instead of that Vostro if you plan on doing only 2D graphic design.

As for personal experience, I have a laptop with a i5-4210u and a GeForce 840m and it ran Photoshop CC flawlessly (even the integrated HD Graphics 4400 was able to handle it fine).

Comment: No, it's not a gtx card, but the [NVidia page about Illustrator's GPU acceleration](http://www.nvidia.com/object/adobe-illustrator-cc.html) notes that it is supported on windows for any Kepler, Maxwell, or Pascall generation GPU. A quick look at the specs for the 940mx says that it's a Maxwell processor. Common sense says that it is newer than a lot of the listed supported processors. It will work.